# London Underground Prims Algorithm

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, algorithms

first time post on Mathematics.

I am an ICT teacher in a secondary school, currently delivering a unit in Mathematics and IT to one pupil in order to get him accepted onto his University degree. I have hit a difficult point. I have explained about Adjacent and Distance matrices and I am able to answer the first 3 questions myself and therefore explain with other examples how he should approach the questions. I am however 'stumped' on the last question as I feel it cannot be answered as I don't have any weightings on the edges (unless I use '1' as the weighting for each edge but that would not be logical or efficient?

The question involves finding out the shortest route from Embankment station to Bond Street station. To be able to do this I know it has to be drawn out as a discrete graph but my problem is that I do not know if you are to use all the stations given or just a portion and what weightings to write on the edges attached to the nodes. I have attached what I think are answers to questions 1-3.

I have no idea what other information I need to provide to make this an acceptable question as I am stumped. Please let me know.

I have attached the screenshot of the question.

[image: Link to Picture with question I am stuck on]
[image: Answer to Question 1]
[image: Answer to question 2]
[image: Answer to question 3]

Using the advice Jaap Scherphuis gave I have attempted this question. I am still not entirely sure I am approaching it correctly? I do understand Prim's Algorithm but I think I am collating too much information which is skewing my results? Attempt is attached as image. I also have a Distance Matrix for all the stops if anyone would like to see it which is attached.

[image: Attempt at question 4]
[image: Really big matrix which I think is too big]

Comment: The question is about the number of stops (which is what you have to minimise), so the edge connecting two stations on the same line has as its weight the number of stops it takes to travel from one to the other. The only nodes that you need to worry about are the stations that lie on more than one line (which includes Embankment and Bond Street), like in question 2.

Comment: It seems to me that a more useful question is to ask for the shortest path from Embankment to Bond Street, instead of building the minimum spanning tree and then measure the distance between the given stations along that tree. The latter is not necessarily the shortest path. For the shortest path you would use Dijkstra's algorithm instead of Prim's algorithm.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I have attempted this question. Would you kindly have a look and see if I am on the right track? I don't think I am. Post has been edited with my attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, the more I think about how Question 4 is worded, the more confusing I find it.

The outcome of [Prim's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm) is a minimum spanning tree, i.e. a tree that connects all the vertices A-T, and has the smallest total weight. This tree is not unique.

You are free to choose any particular vertex to start the algorithm on. It does not matter which, since every vertex will become part of the tree (it has to span the graph).

Also, each time you choose another edge to add to the tree, you are free to choose from any of the adjacent edges that have the minimal possible weight value. This graph has many weight 1 edges, and so there are many possible spanning trees that can result. There is no real reason to choose any one edge over the other as long as they have the same weight.

For example, one spanning tree could be built with [Prim's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm) in this order:

```
A-B 1
B-C 1
C-G 1
A-F 1
F-H 1
H-I 1
I-K 1
K-J 1
K-L 1
L-Q 1
Q-P 1
P-O 1
L-M 1
M-R 1
R-S 1
S-N 1
N-T 2
N-E 2
E-D 1
```

It has 19 edges of course, because there are 20 vertices. Each edge connects a new vertex to the growing tree. The total weight of the finished spanning tree is just 21.

The two stations mentioned in the question (A=Embankment, M=Bond Street) are connected in my spanning tree by a path that happens to be of weight/length 6, through A-F-H-I-K-L-M.

I don't really understand what the question expects from these two stations. A spanning tree is possible that contains the shortest path between those two stations (which is 3 edges long and of total weight 3), but Prim's algorithm is not designed to find the shortest path between two vertices. That is what Dijkstra's algorithm is for.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicions. I may reword the question for my pupil. If I were to use Dijkstra's algorithm would I have to use all stations or just a sample?

Comment: @user3770896  With Dijkstra you would start the algorithm at one of the two stations, and you could stop as soon as you've reached the other station provided all you wanted to know was the optimal route between the two. Or you could continue the algorithm till the whole graph was visited, and then you would have all the optimal paths from that station you started the algorithm on to anywhere else. Most route-finding programs start the algorithm from the goal location, so that it can quickly find the new optimal route to the goal as soon as you take a wrong turn.

Comment: Thanks very much for your time and help, it’s has been very much appreciated.

Comment: @user3770896: Note that you can also perform Dijkstra from **both** the source and destination, and stop once they meet. This is of course more troublesome to program, but will require less work in many cases. If you're interested, there are other search problems that can be very much more efficiently handled by a two-directional technique like this. For example, checkers was recently solved by building both a normal search-tree (forward) and an end-game database (backward). (See [here](https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn12296-checkers-solved-after-years-of-number-crunching).)